# “Pushing” Gmail to GAS — using Gmail forwarding to trigger GAS script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

### Summary

Is it possible to use the Gmail forwarding feature to send (i.e., “push”) via HTTP (GET/POST) to my GAS script URL? (And perhaps include its contents as a parameter?)

### Goal/Background

My goal is to immediately process my incoming Gmail instead of, say, using the GAS trigger feature to query and “pull” my Gmail on a periodic basis.

The former method is relatively immediate. Whereas, the latter method creates an expected delay equal to the mean interval time between (automatically triggered) queries to my inbox.

### Possible Solutions

#### 1. Gmail Data API

[This documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#GmailAtomFeed) states Gmail lacks a data API.

#### 2. Atom/RSS Feeds

Atom/RSS feeds still require an aggregator to pull the data from the server and, thus, do not accomplish my goal of a push-only solution to my GAS URL to, then, in turn, trigger my script via doGet() or doPost().

#### 3. IMAP/POP

These solutions are designed for desktop/offline processing of emails and, therefore, do not meet my goals. I need a solution that lives on the web and automates my web-based email checking tasks.

#### 4. High-frequency GAS Trigger

A, say, 60-second trigger interval in GAS does not work because there is a cost to such high-frequency triggers in GAS due to quota limitations. i.e., I don't want to use up that much quota space on this one task because I need it for other stuff.

#### 5. 3<sup>rd</sup> Party Listeners

I would prefer something free if possible. Someone has suggested [Zapier<sup>®</sup>](http://www.zapier.com) — which does have a free version. Do these work? Are there others?

### Conclusion

Are there any creative ideas out there? Perhaps to point me in a creative direction?

I would even settle for just a way to be immediately notified (programmatically) that I received a new email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger can kick off a script every 60 seconds.  As you stated before, this puts your average notification at 30 seconds (let's not get started on possible flaws in statistical assumptions).

Another possibility for a more immediate action is to use a service like Zapier.com as a listener. It can listen for new emails in your gmail inbox, apply filters, and initiate a GET/POST to the URL for your Apps Script (make sure it is the newest version published).

I hope this helps. Curious why you need immediate handling of the messages ...

Comment: Thanks! This is a promising concept. Immediacy is important because it is one of the specifications of the application I'm building due to its purpose and how it is being used. Time/deadlines and such are involved. There is a cost to a high-frequency triggers in GAS due to quota restrictions, etc. I.e., I don't want to use up that much quota space on this one task. As I will need it for other stuff.

Comment: google appengine have a free service. The cron service may work.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron .. so up to 28 hours per day is free. There is a stackoverflow post somewhere about setting up a link to gmail from appengine.

Comment: immediate handling of the messages is "needed" because running a script every minute to catch an event which happens maybe couple of times a days is stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible from  Google Apps Script:
Google Apps Script currently available events:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

Does Gmail have a Data API?
FAQ: https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#GmailAtomFeed

Looks like IMAP is the only option, not sure if IMAP supports callback.